# Assign correct types to Reselect createSelector function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typescript2.0, reselect

Edit: added package.json excerpt

I am trying to implement typescript in an existing React project and I am facing difficulties with [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library.
Typescript compiler insists on importing the first definition of createSelector function and fails recognize that my function's signature corresponds to another definition.

The definition it imports:

```
export function createSelector<S, R1, T>(
  selector: Selector<S, R1>,
  combiner: (res: R1) => T,
): OutputSelector<S, T, (res: R1) => T>;
```

The one I want to use:

```
export function createSelector<S, R1, R2, T>(
  selectors: [Selector<S, R1>,
              Selector<S, R2>],
  combiner: (res1: R1, res2: R2) => T,
): OutputSelector<S, T, (res1: R1, res2: R2) => T>;
```

Here is my actual code:

```
// groups.selectors.tsx

import { Selector, createSelector } from 'Reselect';
import { IGroup, IQuestionnaire, IGroupReselect, IState } from '../interfaces';

const getGroups:Selector<IState, IGroup[]> = state => state.groups;
const getQuestionnaires:Selector<IState, IQuestionnaire[]> = state => state.questionnaires;

export const groups = createSelector<IState, IGroup[], IQuestionnaire[], IGroupReselect>(
  [getGroups, getQuestionnaires],
  (g, q) => {

    return g.map(group => Object.assign(
      {},
      group,
      {questionnaires: group.questionnairesIds.map(id => q.find(q => q.id === id))}
    ));
  }
);
```

And in case it my be of any help, here is my ts.config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": ".temp",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
    "typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am not completely comfortable with TypeScript so there is certainly something wrong in my implementation. What bugs me is that if I write the simplest possible reselector, that is one with only 1 selector and a combiner of arity 1, it passes type checking which gives me the impression that the compiler does not properly pick the correct definition among overloaded functions in Reselect's [index.d.ts](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect/blob/master/src/index.d.ts)

Here are relevant parts of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^15.0.25",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3"
  },
```

Comment: I would check first to see that you have the version of Reselect's index.d.ts that you linked to. Support for arrays of selectors wasn't added until recently (version 3.0, I think). You could omit the array altogether; it isn't required by reselect (although most of the examples use it.)

Comment: It might indeed be a problem with my dependencies versions. As for array selectors, I am running reselect 3.0.1 so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but from this
[this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13883), it seems to be caused by how the language infers your heterogenous array `[getGroups, getQuestionnaires]` as an array and not a tuple.

Forcing the first argument to tuple type will make it work but causes unnecessary boilerplate

```
const getGroups:Selector<IState, IGroup[]> = state => state.groups;
const getQuestionnaires:Selector<IState, IQuestionnaire[]> = state => 
  state.questionnaires;

const selectors: [Selector<IState, IGroup[]>, Selector<IState, IQuestionnaire[]>] = [getGroups, getQuestionnaires]

export const groups = createSelector<IState, IGroup[], IQuestionnaire[], IGroupReselect>(
  selectors,
  (g, q) => {

    return g.map(group => Object.assign(
      {},
      group,
      {questionnaires: group.questionnairesIds.map(id => q.find(q => q.id === id))}
    ));
  }
);
```